# Why does the town believe Miguel?

Tags: plot-explanation, coco

At the end of ‘Coco’, the town where Miguel lives has banned Ernesto de la Cruz and has glorified Héctor Rivera. I’m assuming this is because Miguel told them about it.

However, **Why would the town authorities believe Miguel?**

I mean, if I went to my town’s authorities and told them that the town’s most famous person had murdered his partner and plagiarised his songs, and said that the person to be remembered was a nobody (who happens to be my ancestor), they would have thrown me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coco_(2017_film)) explains...

> One year later, Miguel proudly presents the family ofrenda – featuring a photo of the now deceased Coco and the mended photo of Imelda and Héctor – to his new baby sister. **Letters saved by Coco contain proof that Ernesto stole Héctor's music**; as a result, Ernesto's legacy is destroyed and the public forgets him and honors Héctor in his place. In the Land of the Dead, Héctor and Imelda join Coco for a visit to the living Riveras as Miguel sings and plays for his relatives, both dead and living.

Comment: nice answer, was wondering the same myself

Comment: Just to emphasise the point to the viewer, the letters are specifically mentioned by a tour guide. I can't recall his exact words, but they are along the lines of "these letters contain phrases from a number of songs you'll recognise, not just 'Remember Me'".